# Generating pattern in each of set of polygons using sp (r)?

Tags: r, sf, sp, spatstat

I have an object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, and for each polygon in the dataframe I have a number of points I would like to generate in that polygon (e.g. I have 130 polygons, and I have a column of 130 integers ranging from 0-10).

Is there a way with sp (or with spatstat, sf, etc.) to generate a random pattern in each polygon using the integer number associated with that polygon?

Comment: You could use `spsample()` to generate a spatially random sample: `spsample(x = polygon, n = polygon$integer, type = "random")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `sp` objects, you need to iterate over the features and call `spsample` for each one with the right number of points to generate. Here's a one-liner given a spatial polygons data frame with column `npts`:

```
p = do.call(
      rbind,
      lapply(
        1:nrow(polys),
        function(i){
          SpatialPointsDataFrame(
            spsample(polys[i,],
                     n=polys$npts[i],
                     type="random"), 
            data=data.frame(srcpoly=rep(i,polys$npts[i]))
           )
         }
        )
        )
```

The returned spatial points data frame records which polygon feature each point came from:

```
> table(p$srcpoly)

   1    2    3    4 
   1   10  100 1000
```

which is from my test set:

[image]

The corresponding function in the `sf` for `sf` class objects is vectorised over `n`, so you do:

```
> pp = st_sample(polys, polys$npts, "random")
```

but you don't get back which polygon each point comes from without doing an  `st_intersection` (or similar) function.

Comment: Perfect! The second code (sf) worked perfectly. Thank you!